# Tags: config vs configuration

Tags: discussion

I notice that there is a tag "[config](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/config)" as well as a tag "[configuration](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration)".  Neither has a wiki summary.

If these tags are meant to be distinct perhaps someone can add a wiki summary that explains the difference.

Or instead maybe one should be a synonym for the other?

I don't currently have the reputation to make these changes myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch, just merged these and created a synonym, and added a wiki description as well.